# why the calculation of eigenvectors and eigenvalues when performing PCA is so effective?

Tags: math, statistics

The core of Principal Componenet Analysis (PCA) lies at calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the variance-covariance matrix corresponding to some dataset (for example, a matrix of multivariate data coming from a set of individuals). Text-book knowledge I have is that:

a) by multipliying such eigenvectors with the original data matrix one can calculate "scores" (as many as orignal set of variables) which are independent from each other

b) the eigenvalues summarize the amount of variance of each score.

These two properties make this process a very effective data transformation technique to simplify the analysis of multivariate data.

My question is why is that so? why is calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors from a covariance-variance matrix results in such unique properties of the scores?

Comment: PCA tells you which vectors give you the most bang for the buck -- that is, which ones contribute the most to the left-hand side of the equation. I might alter your statement (a) a little: from "scores which are independent from each other" to "scores of how independent they are from each other."

Comment: This is a great question, but I wonder if it would be better for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ? And I wonder if this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88537/principal-components-canonical-correlation-and-eigenvalue-problems would help.

Comment: Thanks! I will move the question there. Thanks also for the link.